# Java Keeping Track of Stack's Height

Tags: java, stack

I'm doing a project that will have roughly 20 stacks. I was wondering if there was a relatively easy way to keep track of each stack's height. The only way I could thing was having a separate variable that kept track of the height. The variable would be incremented/decremented when the stacks were popped and pushed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the size() command, inherited from Vector.
Example:

```
    Stack<Integer> s= new Stack<Integer>();
    s.push(3);
    s.push(4);
    s.push(5);
    s.pop();
    System.out.println(s.size());
```

This outputs 2.

Answer (score 1):

For each stack, stack.size() will return it's "Height"--this is so easy it's making me think that I'm misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about `java.util.Stack` it has `size()` method inherited from `Vector`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html